# using a docker container to build another docker image

Tags: continuous-integration, build-process, docker

I am putting my bamboo agents into docker containers so I can config manage and roll out and all that other awesomeness, but I have hit a barrier. One of the things my bamboo agents do is build docker images for other apps. I have not been able to roll that functionality into my docker bamboo agent.

I have read the blog post talking about docker-in-docker
http://blog.docker.io/2013/09/docker-can-now-run-within-docker/

But I don't want to be able to run docker images in side a docker container, I just want to build an image and upload it to the registry.
I have tried implementations of supervisor in order to start the docker daemon along with my agent but this has also proven difficult.

I am running on centos6.4

Am I trying to achieve the impossible?
Is there another way to tackle this that I am not seeing?

thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start a container with your Docker executable and socket as volumes like so:

```
docker run -v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker -v /run/docker.sock:/run/docker.sock  -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash
```

In that container, you can run `docker images` as test to see you can do any Docker command you deem fit, like building and uploading to the registry. I use this myself to run a Jenkins slave with Docker capabilities.

Comment: so if I am interpreting this right, you are passing the docker capabilities of the host into the container as you start it. I'll give this a go  
    $ docker run -v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -i -t bamboo-agent /bin/bash
    bash-4.1# docker images
    2014/03/28 10:37:18 Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker -d' running on this host?
    bash-4.1#
possibly another item needs to be mapped (docker.pid?)

Comment: Try with `docker run  -v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -e /docker.sock`

Comment: Can you call `docker images` on your host? If you can, then I don't know why this would not work. I use this myself as I said. If you use `docker -H ....` or something like that on your host you should also try that in the container.

Comment: I'm getting error about missing library `docker: error while loading shared libraries: libdevmapper.so.1.03: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. Should I mount something else to fix that?

Comment: Update: here is working command: `docker run -v /lib64:/lib64 -v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker -v /run/docker.sock:/run/docker.sock  -i -t ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash`

Comment: This actually is no longer working for me with 1.1. It fails to run the container with an error "Error closing terminal: invalid argument" when mounting /lib64